# "Ask to join" a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air

For an interactive kiosk project I need to add the functionality for the user to "Ask to join" a certain group.

I was imagining this would be pretty straight forward, but I can't really find any trace of this functionality in the Graph API...

Does this functionality exist at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as far as I know you can't programatically make a user join a group (due to security and privacy issues), same goes with liking a page (you have to ask a user to do that manually).

However what I can suggest doing is checking if a given user is already a member of that group  (using the [group_member](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member/) table) and if not, redirecting him to the group and asking him to join it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's a bummer. Since it is in a (public) kiosk environment I can't really allow the users access to the full Facebook page...

Comment: It's public but the user has to log in his facebook account?

Comment: @Kodiak it is possible to authorise the user using Facebook SDK without showing the full Facebook page.

Comment: Sure but I was concerned by the fact the users in a public place have to log into their facebook account on a plublic kiosk. Nevermind, I may have misunderstood something here.